# Ansible AWS create dict of IP addresses grouped by instance tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have several EC2 instances that I need to extract the IP addresses from and group them by a specific instance tag.

So this sample JSON:

```
{
    "changed": true,
    "instances": [ 
        {
            "ami_launch_index": 0,
            "architecture": "x86_64",
            "private_ip_address": "11.111.1.111", 
            "public_dns_name": "",
            "tags": {
                "Environment": "dev",
                "Role": "role1",
            }
        },
        { 
            "ami_launch_index": 0,
            "architecture": "x86_64",
            "private_ip_address": "22.222.2.222",
            "public_dns_name": "",
            "tags": {
                "Environment": "dev",
                "Role": "role1",
            }
        },
        {
            "ami_launch_index": 0,
            "architecture": "x86_64",
            "private_ip_address": "33.333.3.333",
            "public_dns_name": "",
            "tags": {
                "Environment": "dev",
                "Role": "role2",
            }
        },
        {
            "ami_launch_index": 0,
            "architecture": "x86_64",
            "private_ip_address": "44.444.4.444",
            "public_dns_name": "",
            "tags": {
                "Environment": "dev",
                "Role": "role2",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

would yield the following:

```
{
    "role1": [
        "11.111.1.111",
        "22.222.2.222"
    ],
    "role2": [
        "33.333.3.333",
        "44.444.4.444"
    ]
}
```

Getting the instance information from AWS is no problem, but I'm struggling with creating the dictionary that contains the grouped lists of IP addresses. I have tried several variations of the solution offered in [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655303/ansible-aws-create-dict-of-count-of-instance-tags), but have not had any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
- set_fact:
    my_result: "{{ my_result | default({}) | combine({item.0: item.1|map(attribute='private_ip_address')|list}) }}"
  loop: "{{ my_input.instances|groupby('tags.Role') }}"
```

Comment: I thought it might have something to do with the map filter, but I completely missed the "attribute" portion of the documentation. Thank you!